# How to get rid of empty spaces next to dijit.form.DropDownButton inside table cells in IE?

Tags: dojo

I have dijit.form.DropDownButton's inside table cells. However, in IE there are extra spaces next to the dropDownButton inside the cells. How can I get rid of the extra space?

Note that I do not have the problem in Firefox.

Also note that if I remove the div for DropDownButton, the extra spaces are gone in IE. So, it is pretty sure the spaces come with the dropDownButton

The following is my code for the cell

```
<td align="left"><div dojoType="dijit.Toolbar" style="border:none;border-style:none;"><div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton" jsId="SecureData/ShowFilesWrittenToRemoveableDriveIsEncrypted_desc"  showLabel="true" style="background: none;border:none;"><span><div style="font-size:small">ShowFilesWrittenToRemoveableDriveIsEncrypted</div></span><div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog"  ><table><tr><td>Description goes here</td></tr></table></div></div></div></td>
```

Comment: it may be the template HTML that dijit replaces your div with.

Answer (score 0):

Provide "cellpadding" as "0" for the table and make all the div elements to display as inline/inline-block elements, which will not take any extra space around it.

```
td div {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

This will make all div elements inside the .. to be inline with each other.